# How would I do this the best way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-binding

I got a viewmodel with the following attributes:

```
int Balance
int WithdrawAmount
```

A view of mine in my ASP.NET MVC4 application lets the user withdraw money from their balance.
Now when the page is accessed through a GET request I get the users balance and pass it to the view through a `WithdrawViewModel` thus displaying it to the user - in the model the `withdrawAmount` is since the user haven't specified the amount to withdraw yet.

The user enters the desired amount to withdraw and submits a POST request sending the withdraw amount.

Now I bind the `withdrawAmount` to a `WithdrawViewModel` again in order to automatically check if the modelstate is valid (is the amount above 0).

Finally I withdraw the amount etc.

The thing I wanna know is if there's a better way to accomplish this? To me it seems foolish to use the same viewmodel when the values clearly differ (either the balance is in the model or the `withdrawAmount` is in the model) - virtually making them 2 different models.

Can I do it in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the WithdrawAmount, just have the Controller Action method take an `int` parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ViewResult MyMethod(int withdrawAmount){ ... }
```

Comment: Yes but then I can't add validationrules such as the amount have to be above zero etc.

Comment: Then no, you're doing it the best way. It's perfectly fine for the ViewModel to contain both values.

Comment: I see - thanks a lot I just wanted to make sure I don't get used to bad habits.